# How to transform 3rd dimension of Numpy array loaded with ImageIO

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a numpy array of shape `(128,128,3)` loaded from a PNG using `ImageIO`.

Dimension 3 seems to represent RGB values. In this instance all values for Dimension 3 are either `[255,255,255]` or `[0,0,0]` (i.e. white or black).

I want to get rid of the third dimension and replace it with a single 1D array containing 0 for black, and 1 for white. So the end result shape should be `(128,128,1)`.

I've attempted to use combinations of `numpy.reshape` and `numpy.transpose` but I'm really struggling to understand how to do this. I am a beginner to numpy and Python so I may be missing something very simple.

Comment: Please, provide an example with, say, an array of shape `(4,3,2)` and the result you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not missing, and it is very simple. Just index the channel you want:

```
im[:, :, 0]
```

To convert to zeros and ones, you can either make a boolean array:

```
im[:, :, 0].astype(np.bool)
```

or set 255 to one:

```
im = im[:, :, 0]
im[im > 0] = 1
```

A more advanced approach to creating a boolean array would be to view the underlying data as a boolean. This will only work well out of the box if the input is `uint8`:

```
im[:, :, 0].view(dtype=np.bool)
```

Finally, to index the last dimension of an N dimensional array, you can use ellipsis:

```
 im[..., 0]
```

`...` (or the actual name `Ellipsis`) in an index means "use `:` for all dimensions not listed explicitly." You can use it at most once in an index.

In general, you will want to read the documentation on [indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) and later on [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html). There are gentler introductions it there, but the numpy documentation is quite comprehensive and straight from the horse's mouth.

Comment: This has worked great thank you - just a quick question though. In the code im[:,:,0] are we just pulling back the first element of the 3rd dimension? In my case all 3 elements will always be the same so that's fine - just would like to understand better.

Comment: That's exactly what were doing. To get the nth element, do `im[:, :, n]`. `:` means "all elements along this dimension".

Comment: I've added links to my answer for you to peruse